# WSGI app factory pattern and import time created module level objects

Tags: python, sanic

I've been thinking about the *factory pattern* for WSGI applications, [as recommended by the Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appfactories/#basic-factories), for a while now. Specifically about those functions usually being shown to make use of objects that have been created at module import time, like `db` in the example, as opposed to having been created in the factory function.

***Would the factory function ideally create _everything_ anew or wouldn't that make sense for objects like the `db` engine?***
*(I'm thinking cleaner separation and better testability here.)*

Here is some code, where I'm trying to accomplish creating all needed objects for the wsgi app. in its factory function.

```python
# factories.py
def create_app(config, engine=None):
    """Create WSGI application to be called by WSGI server. Full factory function
    that takes care to deliver entirely new WSGI application instance with all
    new member objects like database engine etc.

    Args:
        config (dict): Dict to update the wsgi app. configuration.
        engine (SQLAlchemy engine): Database engine to use.
    """

    # flask app
    app = Flask(__name__)  # should be package name instead of __name__ acc. to docs
    app.config.update(config)

    # create blueprint
    blueprint = ViewRegistrationBlueprint('blueprint', __name__, )
    # request teardown behaviour, always called, even on unhandled exceptions

    # register views for blueprint
    from myapp.views import hello_world
    # dynamically scrapes module and registers methods as views
    blueprint.register_routes(hello_world)

    # create engine and request scoped session for current configuration and store
    # on wsgi app
    if (engine is not None):

        # delivers transactional scope when called
        RequestScopedSession = scoped_session(
            sessionmaker(bind=engine),
            scopefunc=flask_request_scope_func
        )

        def request_scoped_session_teardown(*args, **kwargs):
            """Function to register and call by the framework when a request is finished
            and the session should be removed.
            """
            # wrapped in try/finally to make sure no error collapses call stack here
            try:
                RequestScopedSession.remove()  # rollback all pending changes, close and return conn. to pool
            except Exception as exception_instance:
                msg = "Error removing session in request teardown.\n{}"
                msg = msg.format(exception_instance)
                logger.error(msg)
            finally:
                pass

        app.config["session"] = RequestScopedSession
        blueprint.teardown_request(request_scoped_session_teardown)

    # register blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)

    return app


def create_engine(config):
    """Create database engine from configuration

    Args:
        config (dict): Dict used to assemble the connection string.
    """

    # connection_string
    connection_string = "{connector}://{user}:{password}@{host}/{schema}"
    connection_string = connection_string.format(**config)

    # database engine
    return sqlalchemy_create_engine(
        connection_string,
        pool_size=10,
        pool_recycle=7200,
        max_overflow=0,
        echo=True
    )
```

```python
# wsgi.py (served by WSGI server)
from myapp.factories import create_app
from myapp.factories import create_engine
from myapp.configuration.config import Config

config = Config()

engine = create_engine(config.database_config)
app = create_app(config.application_config, engine=engine)
```

```python
# conftest.py
from myapp.factories import create_app
from myapp.factories import create_engine
from myapp.configuration.config import Config

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    config = TestConfig()
    engine = create_engine(config.database_config)
    app = create_app(config.application_config, engine=engine)
    with app.app_context():
        yield app
```

Answer (score 0):

As you also tagged this with `sanic` I'll answer with that background. Sanic is async and thus relies on an event loop. An event loop is a resource and thus must not be shared between tests but created anew for each one. Hence, the database connection etc also need to be created for each test and cannot be re-used as it is async and depends on the event loop. Even without the async nature it would be cleanest to create db connections per test because they have state (like temp tables).

So I ended up with a `create_app()` that creates everything which allows me to create an arbitrary number of independent apps in a test run. (To be honest there are some global resources like registered event listeners, but tearing those down is easy with py.test factories.) For testability I'd try to avoid global resources that are created on module import. Although I've seen differently in big and successful projects.

That's not really a definite answer, I know...

Comment: "So I ended up with a create_app() that creates everything which allows me to create an arbitrary number of independent apps in a test run." -- That's what I ended up doing aswell. Being able to spawn independent applications, seems like the definition of a factory function to me.

Comment: But in the context of a WSGI app. it comes with some hustle, like collecting routes in the factory function _(otherwise usually registered with a global app object)_ and doing the same with tasks for celery for example. I'm just wondering if I'm overthinking it, as it doesn't seem to bother anybody else...!?

Comment: I've used two methods for registering routes so far: (1) a function which takes the app object and registers all routes or (2) using flask_restful which separates the routes from the app object. The former tends to get a bit cluttered for bigger projects though.